# Getting API hits remaining

Tags: support, api-key

Probably having a brain fart, but I couldn't see a way to get the number of API hits remaining. I know that the limit is 10k per day (I'm using an API key) but because of hte way my app works it would be impossible to keep track of how many hits had been used.

How do I find out how many API hits are remaining for my API key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `X-RateLimit-Current` header contains the requests you have left that particular day. The `X-RateLimit-Max` dictates the total amount of requests your app can make in total through that day.

See the bottom two response headers in the screenshot.

[image: chrome web inspector awesomeness]